# Who is the owner of C and C++?

Tags: c++, c

I just want to know who is the owner of **C** and **C++** like **Oracle** is the owner of **Java** and they release new versions of **Java**. So who can provide updates for C and C++.

Comment: There's no owner but a standardization committee.

Comment: oracle is not the owner of java, standards are defined by jcp and everybody can come up with their own implementation.

Comment: Most languages (human as well as computer) are, thankfully, *not* "owned" in the way that Java (tm) is.

Comment: "Ownership" is an extremely slippery concept in intellectual property law. Asking "who owns C" is a bit like asking "who owns the Internet". There are many different answers, depending on how you approach the question.

Answer (score 11):

C++ and C are designed by (different) ISO committee. The languages are public, with only the official specification being copyright protected and the property of ISO. Anybody can implement the language, however.

In fact two of the popular implementations, Clang and GCC, are open source and free software respectively.